# How to access view of one module in another module in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

My requirement is to share xml view of one module (say app) with another module (say a library module). How can I do this?

I have tried in this way, but the button onClickListener is not working. Where am I going wrong?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Config.LAYOUT_ID, R.layout.login_view);
startActivityForResult(intent, Config.LOGIN_REQUEST);
```

In login_view.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:tag="login_button"/>
```

In onCreate method of LoginActivity from different module

```
        int layoutId = getIntent().getIntExtra(Config.LAYOUT_ID, 0);
        if (layoutId != 0) {
            setContentView(layoutId);
            View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(layoutId, null);

         loginButton = (Button)rootView.findViewWithTag("login_button");
         if (loginButton != null) {
            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Everything is going good, even the control enters `if (loginButton != null)` condition. But when the button is clicked, nothing happens. Where am I going wrong? Or will this approach works? If not, is there any way to do it?

P.S: I have also tried passing the button id through the intent and finding view by that ID. Same exact result.

Comment: try public static content variable?

Comment: You mean accessing static variable of 1st activity in 2nd ? But my problem is that module app depends on module library but not the opposite way.

Comment: Don't listen to @phpdroid. That advice is terrible unless you actually want to create memory leaks.

Comment: any how its not possible in my case even if I do not care about any memory leak which of course I will. Any way, is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one it's work

replace

```
 setContentView(layoutId);
```

with

```
  View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(layoutId, null);
  setContentView(rootView );
```

update this one.

```
int layoutId = getIntent().getIntExtra(Config.LAYOUT_ID, 0);
        if (layoutId != 0) {

            View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(layoutId, null);
          setContentView(rootView );
         loginButton = (Button)rootView.findViewWithTag("login_button");
         if (loginButton != null) {
            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```